# Deploy SAR file in WildFly 29

Tags: java, jboss-eap-7, mbeans, jbossmq, wildfly-27

I have a JAR file which includes few SAR files. Earlier in Jboss AS(4.2.3), upon deploying the jar nested SAR files were getting deployed as well and services were starting, now we are moving to Wildfly 29 (Java 17) and upon adding jar file to deployments directory, deployment is successful but nested files of SAR are not deployed.

How to deploy SAR files in Wildfly 29 Java 17.

Tried to deploy SAR file by placing it in standalone/deployment directory but it keeps giving error for some or the other class being referred by Service Class.

Comment: Did you migrate the SAR to Jakarta EE 10?

Comment: Yes, fixed all the import statements from javax.* to jakarta.*

Comment: What kind of errors are you seeing? Is there a stack trace?

Comment: There are no errors, the deployment is successful and jar.deployed file is also generated. However, nothing is printed in logs related to SAR deployment. Is there any other way to deploy SAR files? Or do I have to mention a dependency on SAR file for deployment?

Comment: Without some kind of reproducer it's hard to say what the issue could be.